# Erlang network issue with parallel HTTP requests

Tags: erlang, httprequest

I'm currently building an HTTP server to supply geographic information.

The first step is to populate this server with geographic information from [geonames.org](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/)

I'd like to automate this process because the GeoNames files change periodically, so I've written a unction that attempts to download the required files in parallel.

Downloading the initial text and ZIP files works fine, but the next step is to parse the downloaded file `countryInfo.txt`, extract all the ISO country codes, then download the corresponding ZIP file for each country code.

When I either restrict the list of country codes to a dozen or so, or perform the downloads sequentially, my code works fine.  But but when I try to request all 252 files in parallel, I get "failed to connect" errors from `httpc:request/4`.

The coding is available from [this Git repo].(https://github.com/ChrisWhealy/Erlang/tree/master/geo_server)

Would error this be due to request throttling on the geonames.org web server or something in my code?

Thanks

Chris W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spawning several hundred processes each connecting to the same server is generally a very bad idea, so bad it is even considered as an [attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack). Most probably some firewall rule kicks in and starts to refuse more connections.

Try to use some kind of thread pool (like [this](https://github.com/inaka/worker_pool)) to queue all requests and execute about 10-20 of them in parallel.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that